# Save the file in the disk against the database with regard to backup and restore

Tags: c#, c++, database, database-design, backup

In the past I have files (documents and images) are stored in the database. People who were advised that it is better to save the file to disk and save the file path in the database.

My questions are:

1. which way is better, save the file in the database or save the file to disk and save the file path in the database?
2. If save the file in the database is better: Field type of file to the file types (DOC, DWG, JPG, ...) what it should be (varbinary(x), varbinary(max), image, ...) ?
3. And if save the file to disk and save the file path in the database it is better:  Incremental backup and restore of files how do I need to implement?

Sincerely

Comment: The advice is subjective to circumstance. How "big" are the files, for one? Your second question doesn't make any sense. Third, again, depends. Fourth is as nonsensical as the second. Five is different question altogether.

Comment: Files between 0.1 to 10 MB. But their number is high.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Save it in database unless you need to write the files on the disk for some operations like viewing the doc files in word, etc And such operations are done often.
2. Use Blob datatype to save the files.
3. If the files are stored in database then implementing the backup and restore functionality in your application will be easier.

   Otherwise you need to get the list of file path from the database and then copy the files from the disk to backup location. Also you will need to update the Paths again in the database.

   There are chances that you get errors reading files from the disk and you need to manage all those things manually.

Comment: Blob datatype as varbinary (max)?

Comment: Yes in SQL Server use varbinary(max). In other databases you will get the option for BLOB